# Deserialization of nested JSONs

Tags: java, serialization, gson, deserialization, objectmapper

I have the following JSON string

```
final String testInputString = "{\"actions\":[{\"actionName\":\"LOGIN\",\"actionAttributes\":{\"emailId\":\"abc@hello.com\",\"password\":\"password\"}},{\"actionName\":\"PERFORM\",\"actionAttributes\":{\"contentId\":\"gti\",\"contentType\":\"EVENT\"}}]}";
```

I am trying to deserialize this to `DeviceActionList.class`, please see class structure below

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DeviceActionList {
    List<DeviceAction> actions;
}

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class DeviceAction {
    @NonNull
    private ActionName actionName;
    private ActionAttributes actionAttributes;
}


public enum ActionName {
    LOGIN,
    PERFORM,
    WAIT,
    CLOSE_PLAYBACK
}

public class ActionAttributes {
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class LoginActionAttributes extends ActionAttributes {
    @NonNull
    private String emailId;
    @NonNull
    private String password;
}

@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class PerformActionAttributes extends ActionAttributes {
    @NonNull
    private String contentId;
    @NonNull
    private String contentType;
}
```

I tried this

```
objectMapper.readValue(testInputString, DeviceActionList.class)
```

However this results in error that It Cannot construct instance of `DeviceActionList` (no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator

Answer (score 0):

The root JSON you provided only contains a `testSuite` field, not a `actions` as `DeviceActionList` expects. You need to create a wrapping class with a field called `testSuite` with type `DeviceActionList` and deserialize the JSON from there:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
public class TestSuite {
    DeviceActionList testSuite;
}

objectMapper.readValue(testInputString, TestSuite.class)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, but I copied the string incorrectly to this question. I updated the question. This still does not work.